# Is the Oxford comma necessary in small, single-worded lists?

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

The main argument: which is advisable of the following two?

> 1. A, B and C
> 2. A, B, and C

Oxford (or serial) comma is useful to avoid ambiguities in phrases that involve lists such as the example given in [this link](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/). I tend to use it in long lists or that which could enclose conjunctions like *'and'* or *'or'* within them like so

> The methods used include regression analysis, trial and error, and statistical inference.

However, how necessary is it when it concerns single-worded lists, especially when it concerns notational identifiers like A, B, C?